# Java enums as integers, Scanner, and menu options

Tags: java, enums, int, java.util.scanner

I am new to Java as well as to enum types.

I am trying to make a menu selection that uses enum types as its valid choices and that displays the following integer selections for the user:

---

Welcome to Frank's Banking Application.

Enter:
    1. Create Bank
    2. Add a branch to a Bank
    3. Add a customer to a Branch
    4. Make a transaction with a customer
    5. Display Banks, Branches, Customers, and Transactions.
    6. Quit Application.

Selection ->

---

However, the problem I am faced with is that enum constants do not seem to accept integer values as their names. So I am stuck making them letters for now. This is the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

enum MenuOptions
{
    z("Continue"), a("Create Bank"), b("Add Branch"), c("Add Customer"),
    d("Make Transaction"), e("Display Information"), q("Quit");

    // field
    private String meaning;

    // constructor
    MenuOptions(String meaning)
    {
        this.meaning = meaning;
    }

    // getters
    public String getMeaning()
    {
        return meaning;
    }
}


public class Main
{
    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Frank's Banking Application.");

        MenuOptions menuOptions = MenuOptions.z;

        while (menuOptions != MenuOptions.q)
            try
            {
                menu();


                menuOptions = MenuOptions.valueOf(input.nextLine());


                switch (menuOptions)
                {
                    case a:
                        //createBank();
                        break;

                    case b:
                        //addBranch();
                        break;

                    case c:
                       // addCustomer();
                        break;

                    case d:
                       // makeTransaction();
                        break;

                    case e:
                        break;

                    case q:
                        System.out.println("Goodbye.");
                        break;

                    default:
                        System.out.println("Selection out of range. Try again");
                }
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Selection out of range. Try again:");
            }


    }

    public static void menu()
    {
        System.out.println("\nEnter:");
        System.out.println("\ta. Create Bank");
        System.out.println("\tb. Add a branch to a Bank");
        System.out.println("\tc. Add a customer to a Branch");
        System.out.println("\td. Make a transaction with a customer");
        System.out.println("\te. Display Banks, Branches, Customers, and Transactions.");
        System.out.println("\tq. Quit Application.");
        System.out.print("\nSelection -> ");

    }
}
```

As can be seen, I had to edit all the enums to have letters as their name in order to allow the user input from the scanner to match their type by using the valueOf method.

Is there a way however, to allow options: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 from user input from keyboard to be taken as a restricted enum type?

Hope that makes sense and thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use e.g.:

```
MenuOptions.values()[1]
```

To get the *second* enum, numbering starts at `0`.

`values()` is an array of all given enum values.

In your case it would be like:

```
MenuOptions.values()[Interger.parseInt(input.nextLine().trim()) - 1]
```

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm. It does throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException but I caught it together with the other one.

Comment: @FrankMeana It would be cleaner to check that the number provided by the user is not exceeding the array size.